# Second Level Subdomain DNS Wildcard

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard

I need help setting up a second level subdomain. I have set up wildcard subdomains in the past with success, but I am having trouble with the DNS entry for this one. I need to do something like

*.design.mydomain.com

So I tried to create an A record with *.design in it but that failed. Is this possible?

Comment: "It failed" is not a proper problem report. What exactly did you do (show the actual file) and what happened exactly?

Comment: Sorry. What I meant by "failed" is I would do a dnsstuff report on the design.mydomain.com  and that would come back fine, then I ran a report on user.design.mydomain.com and that did not come back with any results.

Comment: DNSstuff is a poor way to test a domain. The best tool is dig and, if you want a report from another site, use http://www.zonecheck.fr/ "It did not come back with any results" is clearly not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes you can do this, you basically need a record (bind format)

```
*.design.mydomain.com. 3600 IN A x.x.x.x
```

or in djbdns format:

```
+\052.design.mydomain.com:x.x.x.x:3600
```

Comment: You forgot the dot at the end of *.design.mydomain.com

Comment: and the TTL is in the wrong place too...

Comment: appreciated, should have checked the format of bind (been a while), updated my original post

Answer (score 1):

You did not indicate the name server you use. With BIND or NSD, which both use the RFC 1035 format for zone files, this should work:

```
*.design    IN   A   192.0.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the entry in our BIND config looked something like the following....

```
...... 
hostname               A    IPADDRESSHERE 
$ORIGIN hostname.domain.com.
*                      A    IPADDRESSHERE 
$ORIGIN domain.com.
......
```

We did this in the same zone and it worked just fine for us.

Comment: The $ORIGIN is not necessary, you can just use relative or absolute names.

Comment: I have been doing all our subdomains and MX records this way because of an issue we had when setting up Google Apps.  Google would not validate our account unless I stuck them between ORIGIN calls.  I have no explanation for it.  I understand BIND administration enough to get it done without a lot of trouble, but I wouldn't consider myself an expert.